# Transferring data from Database to multiple pages after selecting Gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView bound to a Database. I want to click a row and display data from the Database that are not in the GridView to 2 pages. I used the DataNavigationFields but that only display what is in the Gridview.

This is my code for the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStock" CssClass="GV" runat="server" enablepagingandcallbackz="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="OnSorting" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging"  PageSize="20">
      <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Text="View" DataNavigateUrlFields="pCode,pID,bCode,SBrand" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetail.aspx?pCode={0}&pID={1}&bCode={2}&SBrand={3}/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pCode" HeaderText="Product Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pID" HeaderText="PID"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="bCode" HeaderText="Bar Code"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SBrand" HeaderText="Brand"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Did you write the code to fetch data from database which is not in the GridView?

Comment: Two options, you can either bind the data and hide them from been displayed or do a database call on OnRowCommand of the grid view to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: @PriyanPerera how can i hide it or call on OnRowCommand ? I am still very new to this

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have connected to the database which stores everything including data not in the GridView if that's what you meant.

Comment: @KHY, sorry misread the question, did not see the view column, can you try adding the bound fields which have the required values you need to send to ProductDetail.aspx page and set them to Visible=false? Also, you will need to add them to DataNavigateUrlFields as well.

Comment: Connected to the database does not mean getting the data from database. You can use RowCommand to to get more data about clicked row from database and display them in other controls. You can read about it in MSDN and other websites if you don't know how to use it

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/rowcommand-event-in-gridview/

Comment: @PriyanPerera This worked but do you know how i can retain the info when going to another page and then returning to ProductDetail.aspx with the info still there? As I have a toggleable tab that is linked to ProductDetail.aspx and ProductDetails2.aspx

Comment: @KHY, there are two options again. You can use ASP.NET AJAX tool kit to send AJAX requests and then ScriptManager.Navigate method to handle navigation events. The other option is to use session state to persist data.

Comment: @PriyanPerera How can i implement that to my project? Also , i managed to display the data in ProductDetail.aspx how can i display it in a second page with tab? Sorry im new to this